# Calculate the determinant of $3\times 3$ matrix with $\sin x$ and powers of $\cos x$

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, problem-solving, determinant

How to calculate the determinant of this matrix
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin x & \cos^2x & 1 \\ 
\sin x & \cos x & 0 \\ 
\sin x & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$$\left[A\right]=\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & \cos^2x & 1 \\ 
\sin x & \cos x & 0 \\ 
\sin x & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=\\=\sin x\begin{vmatrix}
 \cos x& 0\\ 
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}-\cos^2x\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & 0 \\ 
\sin x & 1
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & \cos x\\
\sin x & 1\\\end{vmatrix}=\\=\sin x\cos x-\cos^2x\sin x+\sin x-\sin x\cos x =\\=\sin x\left(\cos x-\cos^2x+1-\cos x\right)=\sin x \left(1-\cos ^2x\right)=\\=\sin x\cdot \sin^2x=\sin^3x$$

The path is something like this? I'm using the wrong rule?

Comment: it is ok: you got the right sign in the middle

Comment: Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: That is correct.  There are probably some simplifications are trig properties you can apply.

Comment: You could also expand using the last column because it contains one zero. This way you have to calculate one less $2 \times 2$ determinants but yeah :)

Answer (score 4):

*The calculation will be easier if you showed zeros:*

Subtract the first row from the second and third row and develop relative the first column we find
$$\det A=\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & \cos^2x & 1 \\ 
\sin x & \cos x & 0 \\ 
\sin x & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & \cos^2x & 1 \\ 
 0& \cos x(1-\cos x) & -1 \\ 
 0& 1-\cos^2x & 0
\end{vmatrix}=\sin x(1-\cos^2x).$$

Comment: Indeed, much easier this way! +1

Comment: I like ... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left[A\right]=\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos^2x & 1\\ \sin x & \cos x & 0 \\ \sin x & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos^2x  \\ \sin x & \cos x  \\ \sin x & 1   \end{vmatrix}=\sin x\cos x+\sin x-\sin x\cos x -\sin x\cos^2x=\\=\sin x\left(1-\cos^2 x\right)=\\=\sin x\cdot \sin^2x=\sin^3 x$$